# Disable Jackson Polymorphic Type Checking in WildFly 20?

Tags: jackson, wildfly, resteasy

Just upgraded to WildFly 20 and am seeing errors related to jackson deserialization e.g.

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'TestCreateRequest' as a subtype of `CreateRequest`: Configured `PolymorphicTypeValidator` (of type `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator`) denied resolution
at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 11]

I have tried setting the system property documented here:

https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.4.2.Final/userguide/html/json.html#Polymorphic_Typing_deserialization

but still get the same errors. Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 5):

Answering my own question...after looking at the RestEasy code on github it turns out the docs give the incorrect system property names. They should be:

"resteasy.jackson.deserialization.whitelist.allowIfBaseType.prefix"
"resteasy.jackson.deserialization.whitelist.allowIfSubType.prefix"